# Format page numbers in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, formatting, siunitx

Consider the following [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)/`biber` minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{abc,
  author  = {A Author},
  title   = {The title},
  journal = {Journal of Journals},
  volume  = {12},
  number  = {34},
  year    = {1234},
  pages   = {12345-23456}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex,siunitx}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

Current page number format: 12345--23456

Ideal page number format: \num{12345}--\num{23456}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to format the page numbers using [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s `\num` command, yielding a range that looks like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can modify the command `\mknormrange` to wrap all page numbers in `siunitx`'s `\num` command. Then we only need to make sure to apply `\mknormrange` also to the `pages` field format (it normally is not applied to that field because Biber does enough pre-processing already).

`biblatex` is quite lenient as to what is regarded as a page number and allows strings other than integers to pass as page numbers (for example `122a`, `iv`), this solution only applies `\num` to those strings passing the stricter `\ifinteger` test. The original definition of the macros modified here can be found in `biblatex.sty`. Essentially we just add the `\ifinteger` test at each call to `\blx@range@out@value` and wrap the page number in `\num` if it is true. For example the original definition of `\blx@normrange@process` was

```
\def\blx@normrange@process#1#2{%
  \blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash#2}}
```

and we make that read

```
\def\blx@normrange@process#1#2{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifinteger{#2}}
    {\@secondoftwo}
  {\blx@range@out@value{\num{#1}\bibrangedash\num{#2}}}
  {\blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash#2}}}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex,siunitx}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@normrange@split#1{%
  \def\blx@normrange@abort{%
    \ifinteger{#1}
      {\blx@range@out@value{\num{#1}}}
      {\blx@range@out@value{#1}}}%
  \blx@imc@ifpages{#1}
    {\blx@normrange@range#1\bibrangedash\bibrangedash&}
    {\blx@normrange@abort}}

\def\blx@normrange@range#1\bibrangedash#2\bibrangedash#3&{%
  \ifblank{#3}
    {\blx@normrange@hyphen#1--&}
    {\ifblank{#2}
       {\ifinteger{#1}
          {\blx@range@out@value{\num{#1}\bibrangedash}}
          {\blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash}}}
       {\ifblank{#1}
          {\ifinteger{#2}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash\num{#2}}}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash#2}}}
          {\blx@range@process{#1}{#2}}}}}

\def\blx@normrange@hyphen#1-#2-#3&{%
  \ifblank{#3}
    {\blx@normrange@abort}
    {\ifblank{#2}
       {\ifblank{#1}
          {\let\blx@tempb\@empty}
          {\def\blx@tempb{#1}}%
        \blx@normrange@hyphen@i#3&}
       {\ifblank{#1}
          {\ifinteger{#2}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash\num{#2}}}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash#2}}}
          {\blx@range@process{#1}{#2}}}}}

\def\blx@normrange@hyphen@i#1-#2&{%
  \def\blx@range@out@value@numdash{\blx@range@out@value{\num{#1}\bibrangedash}}%
  \ifblank{#1#2}
    {\expandafter\ifinteger\expandafter{\blx@tempb}
       {\expandafter\blx@range@out@value@numdash
        \expandafter{\blx@tempb}}
       {\expandafter\blx@range@out@value
        \expandafter{\blx@tempb\bibrangedash}}}
    {\notblank{#1}
       {\ifdefempty\blx@tempb
          {\ifinteger{#1}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash\num{#1}}}
             {\blx@range@out@value{\bibrangedash#1}}}
          {\expandafter\blx@range@process
           \expandafter{\blx@tempb}{#1}}}
       {\blx@normrange@hyphen@i#2&}}}

\def\blx@normrange@process#1#2{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifinteger{#2}}
    {\@secondoftwo}
  {\blx@range@out@value{\num{#1}\bibrangedash\num{#2}}}
  {\blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash#2}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
  author  = {A Author},
  title   = {The title},
  journal = {Journal of Journals},
  volume  = {12},
  number  = {34},
  year    = {1234},
  pages   = {12345-23456},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

Current page number format: 12345--23456

Ideal page number format: \num{12345}--\num{23456}
\end{document}
```

[image: The page numbers in the bibliography show up as formatted with <code>\num</code>: There is a small space between the hundred and the thousand place.]